# Blank entries in a DropDownList using an IList as a dataProvider

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

I'm dynamically creating an IList to use as a dataprovider for a DropDownList in Flex.

The code is creating the IList correctly, and I can access the data inside just fine.

However, when I set the dataprovider for my DropDownList, it only shows blank entries for each  item in the list.

So, if I had 30 items in my IList, I will have 30 blank spots in my dropdown.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
categoryXML = new XML(loader.data);

for each(var category in categoryXML.category) {
    categoryArr.addItem(category.name);
}

categoryList = categoryArr;
cats2.dataProvider = categoryList;
```

What could cause this? I can't seem to find anything via Google.

Comment: How do you display your data, using labelField, labelFunction, custom itemRenderer?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. I set the dataProvider, and I thought that would show what's inside the IList in the dropdown. I guess I need to use something else?

Comment: Okay, so after searching for info about labelField, I'm guessing that I have the information in the dropdown correctly, the entries just don't have a label attached to them, which creates the blank fields. I'll look for a way to add labels.

Comment: Okay, I've changed my addItem line to the following...

    categoryArr.addItem([{label:category.name, data:category.name}]);

And now I get the following inside the dropDown: [object Object]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell without looking at your actual data.  But, it appears you are creating an array of Strings.  I have no idea how a Spark list handles simple values.

You might try something like this:

```
for each(var category in categoryXML.category) {
    var newObject : Object = new Object();
    newObject.label = category.name;
    categoryArr.addItem(newObject.);
}
```

However, if category.name is a complex XML object, then you'll probably need to create a labelFunction.  Something like this:

```
public myLabelFunction(item:Object):String{
  return item.valueToDisplay;
}
```

And set it on the list like this:

```
myList.labelFunction = myLabelFunction;
```